# How to get subdirectory name from string path in java

Tags: java, string, path

I want to get "to" from the below string which is the path of a file.

```
String path="/Path/to/Text.txt";

String path="/The/Path/to/Text.txt";
```

How do i get the subdirectory name "to"?

Comment: Use a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), call the `getName(int)` method.

Comment: Don't work on the String, depending on the system, the separator will change. Use `Path` or `File` to let Java do the hard work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your path is a String:

```
    String[] directories = path.split("/");
    System.out.println(directories[directories.length-2]);
```

But remember to check your path length to avoid indexOutOfBounds

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class:

```
Path p = Paths.get("/The/Path/to/Text.txt");
System.out.println(p.getParent()); // /The/Path/to
System.out.println(p.getParent().getFileName()); // to
System.out.println(p.getName(2)); // to
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has a library class to work with files. It is called `File` (surprisingly...):

```
   import java.io.File;
   //...
   File file= new File("/Path/to/Text.txt");
   File parentDir = file.getParent();
   System.out.println(parentDir.getName());
```